# Javascript object property inaccessible from another property (function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

Quick question, why does my reference to `weekdays` inside `change_date()` give `weekdays is undefined` error in Firebug?

I also tried `this.weekdays`, same.

How do I correct this?

```
var timesheet_common = {

    weekdays : ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],

    change_date: function() {
        $('#text_input').val( weekdays[(new Date()).getDay()] );
    }

};
```

Comment: Maybe you changed the wrong `weekdays`. Only the `weekdays` inside the function should be `this.weekdays`.

Comment: How are you calling change_date? If you are attaching it to an event handler, the this keyword may refer to the object that is firing the event.

Comment: Alex M., you're right. I'm using `$('#selected_date').datepicker({'onSelect':this.change_date});`

Comment: I'm wondering why the `this.change_date` works, but `this.weekdays` doesn't.

Comment: casablanca, yes I did `$('#text_input').val( this.weekdays[(new Date()).getDay()] );`

Comment: so Alex M., the best way around this is just to use `timesheet_common.weekdays`, right?

Comment: @Obay -`$('#selected_date').datepicker({'onSelect':this.change_date});` will not work as `this` refers to the associated input field inside of the `onSelect` function - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ click on the events tab and check out the `onSelect` documentation

Comment: @Obay: I didn't realize you were using `change_date` as an event handler. Event handlers and object methods don't play very well, for the reasons that Alex/Russ mentioned. You really don't need an object in this case then. Can't you just make `change_date` an ordinary function and define `weekdays` inside the function?

Comment: Did you try Marek Kowalski solution? I had some problems like this, too, and they were just matter of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Inside `change_date()` you should refer to `weekdays` as `this.weekdays`, because they're both defined in the same object.
2. When you use `change_date()` as a click handler, you must use `$.proxy(timesheet_common, 'change_date')` instead; doing this makes sure `change_date()` is called within the context of `timesheet_common` rather than the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.weekdays` because it's an object.

Edit: I tried with `this` and it worked for me.

Comment: i get 'this.weekdays is undefined'

Comment: run in Firebug - 
`var timesheet_common = { weekdays : ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],change_date: function() {console.log(this.weekdays);}};timesheet_common.change_date();`

Comment: The exact code above, when run in Firebug says `undefined`? Hmm, that sounds like there's something wrong with your Firebug then :) The function context of the anonymous function assigned to the `change_date` property in the given code is the object literal to which the property belongs. What does it say if you replace `this.weekdays` with `this`?

Comment: @Obay Don't confuse the return value with the log message (ie in Chrome Dev Tools). It definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the function is not associated with its model. You might do sth like this:

```
var timesheet_common = (function(){

    var weekdays = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];

    var change_date = function() {
        $('#text_input').val( weekdays[(new Date()).getDay()] );
    };

    return { weekdays: weekdays, change_date: change_date }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function TimesheetCommon(){
    this.weekdays = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
}
TimesheetCommon.prototype.change_date = function(){
     $('#text_input').val( this.weekdays[(new Date()).getDay()] );
}

var timesheet_common = new TimesheetCommon();
```

Comment: wow i didn't know you could make objects like that in javascript. what's happening here? how come you can already call a `new` on TimesheetCommon? which part of that code turned TimesheetCommon into an object that is `new`-able?

Comment: Every function creates an object when called with new. Add methods to the prototype property as shown above.